# Authentication token storage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to secure every call to my web service via a token.

first the user is authenticated and a authentication token is generated then the token is added to the http runtime and finally the token is then sent to the client (asp.net c# pages)

here is the problem: i want to send the token to every subsequent service call i make. so the question is how do i find out where the token is stored on the client or could i somehow make it store on the client.

any help with be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication tokens (assuming you're using the built-in auth manager) are stored on the client using a cookie named ".ASPXAUTH".

This means that normal cookie storage rules apply. The default lifetime of an auth cookie is 30 minutes; you can override this value in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="..." timeout="60" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

The value for "timeout" is in minutes.

Comment: thanks Heather, and how do i access the value of this token on the client?

Comment: function getCookie(key) {
    var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
}

var authCookie = getCookie('.ASPXAUTH');